# Creating two asynchronous fetch requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, async-await, fetch

After using a fetch request to fill a dropdown box with fields obtained via a fetch request, we select one of those fields and the code should make another fetch request to obtain the data associated with the selected field.

However, while doing this, the second fetch request is not processing after the first. We figured taht was the case because if we use the second fetch request with a pre-set field (and not the one selected on the menu) it works as intended.

The script is as follows:

```
    <script>

    let result;

    let dropdown = document.getElementById('list-occurences');
    dropdown.length = 0;

    let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
    defaultOption.text = 'Choose occurence to edit';

    dropdown.add(defaultOption);
    dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

async function loadOcc() {
    const response = await fetch('https://safeandsoundpw.herokuapp.com/audits/status/0');
    const occ = await response.json();
    let option;
        
    for (let i = 0; i < occ.length; i++) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = occ[i].fk_Audits_occurrence_id;
        option.value = occ[i].fk_Audits_occurrence_id;
        dropdown.add(option);
    }
    
    let selection = document.querySelector('#list-occurences');
        selection.addEventListener('change', () => {
            result = parseInt($('#list-occurences option:selected').val());
        });
    
    let response2 = await fetch(`https://safeandsoundpw.herokuapp.com/occurrences/$(result)`);
    const occ2 = await response.json();
    
    $.each(occ2, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value);
        $('#teamManager').append(`${value.fk_Occ_manager_id}`);
        $('#place').append(`${value.place}`);
        $('#date').append((`${value.start_date}`).slice(0,10).split("-").reverse().join("/"));
    });

    return occ;
}

console.log(result);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    let occ = [];

    try {
        occ = await loadOcc();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error!");
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(occ);
});

</script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The second response will run after the first one, because that's how `await` works, but this is incorrect: `$(result)` you want braces, not parens; and you're not assigning to default until insight a changehandler, which means you probably want to lift the second fetch and its related code inside the same changehandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second fetch has to be inside the dropdown change handler.

```
let selection = document.querySelector('#list-occurences');
selection.addEventListener('change', () => {
  result = parseInt($('#list-occurences option:selected').val());
  
  let response2 = await fetch(`https://safeandsoundpw.herokuapp.com/occurrences/${result}`); // Fixed the brace issue here
  const occ2 = await response2.json();  // Await response2... The "2" was missing
  
  $.each(occ2, function (index, value) {
      console.log(value);
      $('#teamManager').append(`${value.fk_Occ_manager_id}`);
      $('#place').append(`${value.place}`);
      $('#date').append((`${value.start_date}`).slice(0,10).split("-").reverse().join("/"));
  });
    
});
```